# Dont wrap row of divs

Tags: css

How to create set of `float:right` divs one next to another and make them not wrap, no matter how much of them exists or how wide is any of them. If they together are wider than viewport, then x-scroll should appear.

Content inside those divs should wrap normally.

CSS only would be good.

Comment: Set `overflow:auto` on the parent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Style the parent element with `white-space: nowrap;`, though this only works with `display: inline` (or `display: inline-block;`) elements. Given the following HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <!-- there's quite a lot of these... -->
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#parent {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#parent .child {
    display: inline-block;
    /* there's some other CSS for aesthetics */
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/u7fKa/).

Unfortunately I don't think there *is* a way of forcing `float`-ed elements to not wrap to a new line.

To preserve or, rather, *force* normal line-wrapping for descendant elements you'll have to explicitly over-ride the inheritance and set `white-space: normal` (as well as, possibly, define a `width` or `max-width`)

```
/* other CSS remains intact */

#parent .child {
    display: inline-block;
    /* irrelevant/aesthetic CSS */
    white-space: normal;
    max-width: 8em;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/u7fKa/1/).

Comment: What about setting children content wraping normally.

Comment: it accidentally could be only: .parent {white-space:nowarp;} .parent > * {white-space:normal;}

Answer (score 0):

Few elements: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/A8duy/

Many elements: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/A8duy/1/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="block-container">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
</div>​
```

**CSS:**

```css
.block-container {
    text-align: right;
    white-space: nowrap;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    border: 1px solid red;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}
.block-container > div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
    text-align: left;
    white-space: normal;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```